# How to Use Jsonschema Draft 7 if-then-else based on boolean?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to define a json schema that requires some fields if a control field is true. I just made the following schema (I tried more than 1 solution from google, so there is some differences between the if statements...):

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "if": {
    "not": {
      "properties": {
        "ldap_enable": {
          "enum": [ false ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": ["ldap_binddn", 
                 "ldap_bindpassword",
                 "ldap_server",
                 "ldap_searchdn",
                 "ldap_searchfilter",
                 "ldap_mappings",
                 "ldap_needtls" 
                ]
  },
  "if": {
    "properties" : {
      "telegram_alert": {
        "enum": [ 
        true 
       ]
      }
    }
   },
  "then": {
    "required": ["telegram_chat", 
                 "telegram_token"
                ]
  },
  "if": {
    "properties" : {
      "email_alert": {
        "enum": [ 
        true 
       ]
      }
    }
   },
  "then": {
    "required": ["email_sender", 
                 "email_host",
                 "email_port"
                ]
  },
  "required": [
    "mysql",
    "port",
    "tmp_path",
    "cookie_hash",
    "cookie_encryption",
    "web_host",
    "concurrency_mode",
    "max_parallel_tasks",
    "email_alert",
    "telegram_alert",
    "ldap_enable"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mysql": {
      "$id": "#/properties/mysql",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Mysql Schema",
      "required": [
        "host",
        "user",
        "pass",
        "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "host": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/host",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "DB Address",
          "default": "db",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "user": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/user",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Username for DB",
          "default": "semaphore",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "pass": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/pass",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "User Password",
          "default": "semaphore",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "name": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/name",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Schema Name on DB",
          "default": "semaphore",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        }
      }
    },
    "port": {
      "$id": "#/properties/port",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The port where app will listen.",
      "default": "3000"
    },
    "tmp_path": {
      "$id": "#/properties/tmp_path",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The path where the playbooks will be temporary placed.",
      "default": "/tmp",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "cookie_hash": {
      "$id": "#/properties/cookie_hash",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Cookie Hash for Site",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "cookie_encryption": {
      "$id": "#/properties/cookie_encryption",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Cookie_encryption",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "email_sender": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_sender",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "semaphore@localhost",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "email_host": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_host",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Email_host Schema",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "email_port": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_port",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Email_port Schema",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "web_host": {
      "$id": "#/properties/web_host",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Web_host Schema",
      "default": "http://localhost:3000",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_binddn": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_binddn",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Ldap Bind User.",
      "examples": [
        "cn=bla,dc=com"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_bindpassword": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_bindpassword",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Ldap Bind Password",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_server": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_server",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Ldap Server",
      "default": "ldap",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_searchdn": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_searchdn",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Ldap_searchdn Schema",
      "examples": [
        "ou=user,dc=example"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_searchfilter": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_searchfilter",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Ldap_searchfilter Schema",
      "examples": [
        "(uid=%s)"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_mappings": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Ldap_mappings Schema",
      "required": [
        "dn",
        "mail",
        "uid",
        "cn"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "dn": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/dn",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Dn Schema",
          "default": "dn",
          "examples": [
            "dn"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "mail": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/mail",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Mail Schema",
          "default": "mail",
          "examples": [
            "mail"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "uid": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/uid",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Uid Schema",
          "default": "uid",
          "examples": [
            "uid"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "cn": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/cn",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Cn Schema",
          "default": "cn",
          "examples": [
            "cn"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        }
      }
    },
    "telegram_chat": {
      "$id": "#/properties/telegram_chat",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Telegram_chat Schema",
      "examples": [
        "asdfasdf"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "telegram_token": {
      "$id": "#/properties/telegram_token",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Telegram_token Schema",
      "examples": [
        "asdfasdf"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "concurrency_mode": {
      "$id": "#/properties/concurrency_mode",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Concurrency_mode Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "max_parallel_tasks": {
      "$id": "#/properties/max_parallel_tasks",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "The Max_parallel_tasks Schema",
      "default": 0
    },
    "email_alert": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_alert",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Email_alert Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    },
    "telegram_alert": {
      "$id": "#/properties/telegram_alert",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Telegram_alert Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    },
    "ldap_enable": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_enable",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Ldap_enable Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    },
    "ldap_needtls": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_needtls",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Ldap_needtls Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then I just checked the following json against the schema:

```
{
    "mysql": {
        "host": "db",
        "user": "semaphore",
        "pass": "semaphore",
        "name": "semaphore"
    },
    "port": "",
    "tmp_path": "/bla",
    "cookie_hash": "93n2lvoStnqjskpqea5P+04hPo1CEoEj9fJ68BARtYA=",
    "cookie_encryption": "602ZDI0qYlScN+FH6ivx75ERWfS+0E4aHV5WaYGHI4s=",
    "email_sender": "semaphore@localhost",
    "email_host": "server",
    "email_port": "25",
    "web_host": "http://whoknows",
    "telegram_chat": "asdfasdf",
    "telegram_token": "asdfasdf",
    "concurrency_mode": "",
    "max_parallel_tasks": 0,
    "email_alert": true,
    "telegram_alert": true,
    "ldap_enable": true,
    "ldap_needtls": true
 }
```

I just expected a validation error here, the ldap_* fields should be required because ldap_enable is true, but instead "https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/" site and python jsonschema lib returns that the json is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have keyword duplication (`if`, `then`) at root level of your schema. If multiple conditions are needed you can group them with `oneOf`, `allOf`, `anyOf` arrays depending on your requirements.

Please check this schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "ldap_enable": {
            "enum": [
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "ldap_binddn",
          "ldap_bindpassword",
          "ldap_server",
          "ldap_searchdn",
          "ldap_searchfilter",
          "ldap_mappings",
          "ldap_needtls"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "telegram_alert": {
            "enum": [
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "telegram_chat",
          "telegram_token"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "email_alert": {
            "enum": [
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "email_sender",
          "email_host",
          "email_port"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "required": [
    "mysql",
    "port",
    "tmp_path",
    "cookie_hash",
    "cookie_encryption",
    "web_host",
    "concurrency_mode",
    "max_parallel_tasks",
    "email_alert",
    "telegram_alert",
    "ldap_enable"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mysql": {
      "$id": "#/properties/mysql",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Mysql Schema",
      "required": [
        "host",
        "user",
        "pass",
        "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "host": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/host",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "DB Address",
          "default": "db",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "user": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/user",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Username for DB",
          "default": "semaphore",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "pass": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/pass",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "User Password",
          "default": "semaphore",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "name": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mysql/properties/name",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Schema Name on DB",
          "default": "semaphore",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        }
      }
    },
    "port": {
      "$id": "#/properties/port",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The port where app will listen.",
      "default": "3000"
    },
    "tmp_path": {
      "$id": "#/properties/tmp_path",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The path where the playbooks will be temporary placed.",
      "default": "/tmp",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "cookie_hash": {
      "$id": "#/properties/cookie_hash",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Cookie Hash for Site",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "cookie_encryption": {
      "$id": "#/properties/cookie_encryption",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Cookie_encryption",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "email_sender": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_sender",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "semaphore@localhost",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "email_host": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_host",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Email_host Schema",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "email_port": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_port",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Email_port Schema",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "web_host": {
      "$id": "#/properties/web_host",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Web_host Schema",
      "default": "http://localhost:3000",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_binddn": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_binddn",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Ldap Bind User.",
      "examples": [
        "cn=bla,dc=com"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_bindpassword": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_bindpassword",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Ldap Bind Password",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_server": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_server",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Ldap Server",
      "default": "ldap",
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_searchdn": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_searchdn",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Ldap_searchdn Schema",
      "examples": [
        "ou=user,dc=example"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_searchfilter": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_searchfilter",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Ldap_searchfilter Schema",
      "examples": [
        "(uid=%s)"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "ldap_mappings": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Ldap_mappings Schema",
      "required": [
        "dn",
        "mail",
        "uid",
        "cn"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "dn": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/dn",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Dn Schema",
          "default": "dn",
          "examples": [
            "dn"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "mail": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/mail",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Mail Schema",
          "default": "mail",
          "examples": [
            "mail"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "uid": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/uid",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Uid Schema",
          "default": "uid",
          "examples": [
            "uid"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "cn": {
          "$id": "#/properties/ldap_mappings/properties/cn",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Cn Schema",
          "default": "cn",
          "examples": [
            "cn"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        }
      }
    },
    "telegram_chat": {
      "$id": "#/properties/telegram_chat",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Telegram_chat Schema",
      "examples": [
        "asdfasdf"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "telegram_token": {
      "$id": "#/properties/telegram_token",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Telegram_token Schema",
      "examples": [
        "asdfasdf"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "concurrency_mode": {
      "$id": "#/properties/concurrency_mode",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Concurrency_mode Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "max_parallel_tasks": {
      "$id": "#/properties/max_parallel_tasks",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "The Max_parallel_tasks Schema",
      "default": 0
    },
    "email_alert": {
      "$id": "#/properties/email_alert",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Email_alert Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    },
    "telegram_alert": {
      "$id": "#/properties/telegram_alert",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Telegram_alert Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    },
    "ldap_enable": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_enable",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Ldap_enable Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    },
    "ldap_needtls": {
      "$id": "#/properties/ldap_needtls",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Ldap_needtls Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    }
  }
}
```